# how to dynamically generate expression in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in which I have generated name of check box dynamically , which comes inside a loop, I have added loop id to the name and the name is generated for each row of the table (which is still the same ), I am trying to capture this variable in jquery , the expression comes fine but while running the code I am getting error **"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:"** , below is my Jquery code :

```
 $('.select_all').on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log("inside select all click id is :" + id)
        var cbox = "'"+id+"checkBox"+"'";
        var c ="\"input[name="+cbox+"]\"";        
        if($("#" + $(this).attr(id) + " INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true)){
            console.log("inside this");         
            $(c).each(function(){
                console.log("inside ckbox")
              this.checked = true;                
        });         
        }else{
            $(c).each(function(){
                this.checked = false; 
            });
            
        }   
 });
```

here the variable c is formed like  **"input[name='1checkBox']"**  which is correct , but when it comes to the $(c).each part , it throws the above mentioned error. Can some let me know how the dynamic expressions are created and run in jquery . Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('"input"')` is not valid - you've got too many `"`

Comment: that quote , I placed in the question , let me remove it , in the code the quotes are correct.

Comment: This `if($("#" + $(this).attr(id) + " INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true)){` should be changed to `if($("#" + $(this).attr(id) + " INPUT[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')){`

Comment: Why don't you use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: It's also in the code: `var c ="\"input[name="+cbox+"]\"";  `

Comment: "*it doesn't work without them*" - well, it **clearly** doesn't work *with* them - so maybe you're asking the wrong question?  This is classic XY problem - you've got a problem A, tried to fix it with B, B didn't work so you've asked why B doesn't work - instead ask about A.

Comment: Your *actual* issue is solved using classes or relative DOM navigation.  If you could include some HTML that shows how the select_all and XcheckBox(es) relate to each other, we can provide a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```js
$(`input[name='${cbox}']`)
```

Example:

```js
const name= "password"
console.log($(`input[name="${name}"]`)[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="password"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the redundant `"` marks enveloping the selector: instead of

```
var c ="\"input[name="+cbox+"]\"";
```

do simply

```
var c ="input[name="+cbox+"]";
```

Comment: That did not work , that's why I had to include the quotes .

Comment: And more simply: `\`input[name="${cbox}"]\``

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve my issue by changing the code , below is the JS code which I used .

```
$('.select_all').on("click", function(event) {
     console.log("inside event propogation")
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

$('.select_all').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');        
    var cbox = "'"+id+"checkBox"+"'";   
    if(this.checked) {                  
        $("[name="+cbox+"]").each(function(){               
          this.checked = true;                
    });         
    }else {
        $("[name="+cbox+"]").each(function(){       
             this.checked = false;
            
        });
    }               

});
```